# Interfacing SST26VF064B (External Memory) with STM32F429I Discovery Board

Tags: arm, spi, stm32f4discovery

I am using stm32f429i Discovery board to interface SST26VF064B (Memory) over SPI communication protocol. I did all the connection and use the following HAL libraries code to read its identity register(`0X9F`), status register(`0X35`):

```
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_2,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
spitxbuf[0]=0X9F|0X80;
HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi2,spitxbuf,1,50);
HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi2,spirxbuf,1,50);
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_2,GPIO_PIN_SET);
```

I am receiving `00` as the response. What am I doing wrong? I used the same configuration code (using `SPI5`) to read the on board Accelerometer. It worked, but with the external memory it is not working.

Comment: `spitxbuf[0]=0X9F|0X80;` I advice a basic C book first.

Comment: you have a scope to look at the spi bus with?  if not bit banging then you should probably have a scope.